# Select Query With hint for add Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

my select Query is:

```
Select A.DocumentID,
       A.CodingID,
       A.DebitPrice,
       A.CreditPrice,
       A.DocumentDetailDescriptionID,
       A.HKSID,
       A.OldInc,
       A.EffectiveDate,
       A.DetailedAccount1ID,
       A.DetailedAccount2ID,
       A.DetailedAccount3ID,
       C.FinancialPeriodID,
       C.SalesCompanyID,
       B.[Date]
 From  acc.DocumentDetail A
 INNER JOIN ACC.Document B ON B.DocumentID = A.DocumentID
 INNER JOIN ORG.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod C ON C.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID = B.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID
```

acc.DocumentDetail have about 12917388 record

acc.documet have about 131767 record

org.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod have about 93 record

my query is slow and I want to make it faster. what hint I must to use ?

Comment: Hint?  What about indexes on the columns used for joining.

Comment: You don't have a where clause, so you're retrieving at least 12 million records - how slow is it?

Comment: 1- CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DocumentDetail_DocumentID] ON [ACC].[DocumentDetail] ([DocumentID] ASC)ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: 2- Create TABLE [ACC].[DocumentDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentDetail_DocumentDetailID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DocumentDetailID] ASC)ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: 3- Create TABLE [ACC].[Document] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DocumentID] ASC)ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: 4- CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Document_SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] ON [ACC].[Document] ([SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] ASC)ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: 5- ALTER TABLE [ORG].[SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] ASC)ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: You can edit your question to add details like this. It's much easier to read than comments.

Comment: Execution time of this Query is about 2:11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important questions regarding this situation:

1. Are you going to the overall best performance or are you wanting to return the first rows faster (better suited for UI applications)?
2. Does the table org.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod acts like a *filter* or a *dictionary*?

If you are looking for better overall time and SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod acts like a dictionary, the best performance can be achieved by using a MERGE join between Document and DocumentDetail and, then, using a HASH join to SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod.

```
SELECT (...)
FROM acc.Document doc
INNER MERGE JOIN acc.DocumentDetail det ON (...)
INNER HASH JOIN org.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod fnp ON (...)
OPTION(FORCE ORDER);
```

If SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod acts like a filter or this query is to be used into a UI application, you can return the first rows faster by beginning with this table and then using LOOP/HASH join with Document and then, again, another LOOP/HASH join with DocumentDetail. The choice between LOOP or HASH join depends on many environment variables, so I'd rather specify the order of the JOIN and let the engine choose the join:

```
SELECT (...)
FROM org.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod fnp
INNER JOIN acc.Document doc ON (...)
INNER JOIN acc.DocumentDetail det ON (...)
OPTION(FORCE ORDER);
```

More important than the hints for the query performance, though, is the index structure of these tables. For this query matters, I'd suggest the following indexes (valid for both usage cases):

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idxc_det
  ON acc.DocumentDetail(DocumentID, CodingID);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idxc_doc
  ON acc.Document(DocumentID);

CREATE INDEX idx_fnper
  ON acc.Document(SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idxc_doc
  ON org.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod(SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all.

I Survey My Query and add Index in SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod On SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID and Include SalesCompanyID & FinancialID
and change my Query to below (this query is faster about 1:10)

```
Select  A.DocumentID,
    A.CodingID,
    A.DebitPrice,        
    A.CreditPrice,        
    A.DocumentDetailDescriptionID,        
    A.HKSID,        
    A.OldInc,        
    A.EffectiveDate,        
    A.DetailedAccount1ID,        
    A.DetailedAccount2ID,        
    A.DetailedAccount3ID,        
    C.FinancialPeriodID,        
    C.SalesCompanyID,        
    B.[Date]  
From  acc.DocumentDetail A  
INNER HASH JOIN ACC.Document B ON B.DocumentID = A.DocumentID  
INNER LOOP JOIN ORG.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod C ON C.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID = B.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID
```